# Finding the mean of a column of data

Tags: r, mean

```
    # What is the mean suspension rate for schools overall?
    merged_data[merged_data == "*"]<- NA
    na.omit(merged_data)
    as.numeric(suspension_rate_total)
    suspension_rate_total <- merged_data[ ,7]
    mean(suspension_rate_total)
```

I'm trying to find the mean of the column "suspension_rate_total." I thought maybe it was not allowing me to find the mean because I had *'s, which is why I turned them into NA's and deleted them. But I'm still showing lots of NA's in my data, and lots of numbers, as opposed to one, singular mean. Help!

This is my data (not sure how to insert it here tidied).

**Data**

```
structure(list(schid = c("1030642", "1030766", "1030774", "1030840", 
"1130103", "1230150"), farms = c(132, 116, 348, 406, 68, 130), 
    foster = c("2", "0", "1", "8", "1", "4"), homeless = c("14", 
    "0", "8", "4", "1", "4"), migrant = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0"), ell = c("18", "12", "114", "45", "7", "4"), suspension_rate_total = c(NA, 
    20, 0, 0, 95, 5), suspension_violent = c(NA, "9", "0", "0", 
    "20", "2"), suspension_violent_no_injury = c(NA, "6", "0", 
    "0", "47", "1"), suspension_weapon = c(NA, "0", "0", "0", 
    "8", "0"), suspension_drug = c(NA, "0", "0", "0", "9", "1"
    ), suspension_defiance = c(NA, "1", "0", "0", "9", "1"), 
    suspension_other = c(NA, "4", "0", "0", "2", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I re-ran the data and it's pulling up issues once again. :( This is the code: ```{r}
# What is the mean suspension rate for schools  overall?
mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total,na.rm = T)

# What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms > 100? 
mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$farms < 100], na.rm = T)

# What is the mean suspension rate for schools with farms < 100? 
mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$farms < 100], na.rm = T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your data is called df:

```
mean(df$suspension_rate_total,na.rm = T)
```

most colums are class character, convert them to numeric to calculate all column means:

```
df<-apply(df,2,as.numeric)

colMeans(df, na.rm = T)
```

Comment: You're amazing thank you so much. I had spent probably three hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: What if I want to find the mean of the suspension rates for a specific subset of data. Say, I need to find suspension rates when farms (another column) is greater than 100.

Comment: Ah, nvm. This worked: mean(merged_data$suspension_rate_total[merged_data$farms > 100], na.rm = T)

Comment: library(dplyr)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df %>% dplyr::filter(df$farms > 100) %>% colMeans(., na.rm=T)

Comment: please mark the  answers as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. : )